# Why encrypt a web config file?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, passwords, encryption

As far as I can tell, any section in a web.config file can be encrypted & decrypted using aspnet_regiis.exe.

If aspnet_regiis can be used to decrypt the web.config file, then what's the point of encrypting it? Is it just to keep passwords & sensitive information from being stored as plain text? If anyone with the file and the exe can decrypt it, does it really protect sensitive config info?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to everyone who answered regarding the machine key. The reason I asked this question is because we have an open source project hosted at codeplex.com. However, we also deploy this project to Windows Azure. I am trying to find a best approach to keep the sensitive passwords out of source control, but keep them accessible as part of my project for when I deploy to Azure.

Currently, I am using web config transforms to store the Azure connection strings (as well as Gmail passwords for system.net). I've created a Web.PublishToAzure.config transform file, and just kept that file out of source control. I also found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/09/10/10060395.aspx) which may be a better option. Thanks again.

Comment: The link to "this article" doesn't exists. I would really like to have a look at if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplistic answer: they won't have access to the key

I believe by default the key is stored in the machine's certificate store, so a malicious user would need to have access to that too. I'm not an expert but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 10):

The file is encrypted using machine-specific keys. While it is true that anyone with machine-level access could decrypt it, encrypting it would stop people with FTP access since they don't have the machine's DPAPI keys.

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that the aspnet_regiis.exe uses a machine specific key as a "salt"

If you encrypt a section on a machine, and then take the config to another machine and try to decrypt it, it will not work.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the part about moving the encrypted file to another machine.

Answer (score 6):

In history, there were exploits in browsers or web server software that allowed users to view any file on the server's hard drive.  In a case such as this, the encrypted web.config file could be of some use.   However if a web server has been compromised allowing remote access to the server itself, then having an encrypted web.config file will be the least of your worries.

Comment: Agreed. I am thinking more in terms of keeping the passwords and other sensitive info out of source control.